# Is the set of arithmetic progressions isomorphic to $F^2$?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, vector-space-isomorphism

Q) Let $V(F)$ be the vector space of all arithmetic sequences over the field $F$ (real). i.e. all
sequences of the form ${a, a+d, a+2d, ...}$ Then prove or disprove that $V(F)$ is isomorphic
to $F^2$.

My first intuition says the answer is YES, dim($V(F)$) = 2 as it has two variable parameters $a$ and $d$, and dim($F^2$) = 2, so $V(F)$ is isomorphic to $F^2$.

But considering a general term of an AP(Arithmetic Progression) is written as $a_n=a+(n-1)d$, which gives 3 variable parameters $a,d,n$, therefore making dim(V(S))=3 and the result NO.

In this entire discussion one thing which I am extremely confused with is how to represent the basis of V(F).

Please suggest where I'm wrong and the representation of basis vectors of V(F).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $n$ is not a “variable parameter”. Your conclusion, dim$(V(F))=3$, is so bizarre.

Comment: Your first intuition is correct. If you want a basis, you can take the sequence corresponding to $a=1,d=0$ (in other words, the constant sequence $1,1,1,\ldots$), plus the sequence corresponding to $a=0,d=1$ (in other words, the constant sequence $0,1,2,3,\ldots$). When you write $a_n=a+(n-1)d$, $n$ is indeed a parameter, but not a parameter intervening in the definition of the sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: Yes it does thanks.